# How to use transactional email service in Ruby to send an activation account email to user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently doing a `Ruby` on `Rails` Tutorial (https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-6th-edition-tutorial/account_activation#sec-activation_email_in_production) Chapter 12.

My Sample App is deployed in `Heroku` and I'm trying to install `SendGrid` to send emails on production environment, and when I click on this add-on redirects me to a SendGrid URL that says:

"Access to sendgrid.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

And I also used `gmail` to do it, it worked (i saw it in my `console`) but immediately I received an email from `Google` with a Critical security alert instead of the actual `user` `account activation` email.

So I find a transactional email service, `sendinblue`, but I don't know how to use it for email account activation.

Comment: To send mails through Gmail you have to whitelist the ip of your heroku app, the email sender and jump through various security related hoops. You should really try [MailGun](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mailgun) instead which has a Heroku addon and a free tier and is dead simple to setup.

Comment: @maxcal  thank you so much. I used MailGun and it works perfectly.